# How to filter result of CAN bus for IDs with Python-Can and Raspberry

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, can-bus

Hello I have a Raspberry with an MCP2515 CAN bus device, for read entire values of broadcasting it's only this source in Python with use of python-can:

```
import can 
bus = can.interface.Bus(channel='can0', bustype='socketcan_native') 
notifier = can.Notifier(bus, [can.Printer()])
```

I need to filter that result for id, how it work? Can anybody make an example of it's possible make a filter? I watched on website of library and this is the web page of filtering:
https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bus.html#filtering

How it work? Thanks a lot for reply.

Answer (score 6):

You should set the filter using the [`set_filters()`](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/bus.html#can.BusABC.set_filters) method of your instance of the `Bus` class. The argument is an iterable of dictionaries each containing a `can_id`, a `can_mask`, and an optional `extended` key.

```
bus.set_filters([{"can_id": 0x11, "can_mask": 0x21, "extended": False}])
```

Check out the [internal api docs](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/bus.html#can.BusABC.set_filters) for more detailed information.

Comment: More info on [`set_filters()`](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/bus.html#can.BusABC.set_filters)

Answer (score -2):

I think what this means is that

```
def on_message_received:
    set_filters(can_filters{"can_id": 0x11, "can_mask": 0x21})
```

Another reference [Json] https://github.com/normaldotcom/CANard/blob/master/examples/example_db.json

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? `set_filters()` is a function of the `bus` class so wouldn't you need to call that on the bus you try to filter? Asking cause I have the same problem as OP and I can't get my filters to work.

Comment: This is wrong. You shouldn't be calling set_filters in your receive callback, plus you have syntax errors.